# Bootstrap - columnas que haga un salto de página para cierta clase de columnas

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

Tengo este código donde pongo las columnas en una `grid` de `bootstrap` 4,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <img src="local.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
        Dirección<br>
        Pruebas 1234
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <img src="telefono.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
        Teléfono<br><b>900 XXX XXX</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto en dekstop hace lo siguiente (lo muestra todo en un `row`):

**local.png** | Dirección | **Telefono.png** | Teléfono 900 XXX XXX

Pero en formato mobile es decir cuando sea `col-sm-5 o col-xs-5` lo que quiero es que después de "dirección" haga un salto y quede de esta manera:

**local.png**    | Dirección

**Telefono.png** | Teléfono 900 XXX XXX

Creo que había alguna clase que le podías decir esto, pero no consigo encontrarla.

Adjunto una captura del resultado que tengo ahora y del resultado que espero
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: El grid de bootstrap es de 12 columnas, es decir que si quieres que un elemento ocupe una linea tienes que poner `col-tamaño-12`

Comment: Prueba con `DataTables`. Se integra con `Bootstrap`, te ahorra tiempo y queda con un diseño muy agradable a la vista. 

Documentación datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/integration/… 

Inspecciona el ejemplo con las herramientas de desarrollo de Chrome.

Comment: Quiero hacerlo con las columnas de boostrap, adjunto una captura en el primer post con lo que intento hacer

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien como quieres el resultado. Si no he entendido mal, podrias poner a un div o a un br la clase de .d-none .d-sm-block .d-md-none.

Fuente:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Comment: Hola Marcos, bienvenido a la comunidad. Tu respuesta parece más un comentario, para pedir aclaración, usamos los comentarios. Además, las respuestas con solo enlaces pueden ser consideradas de baja calidad y terminan cerradas. Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), así te das una idea de las normas de la comunidad para dar respuestas de calidad y evitar que sean eliminadas.